# innerHTML and outerHTML property on HTMLElement return undefined with no error

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, react-native, html-parsing

**Goal: Take a HTML as string, edit some attributes of image tags in it, return the HTML as string.**

My function is along following lines:

```
private resolveImagesInHTML (body: string): string {

    let htmlParser = new domParser.DOMParser();     // from react-native-html-parser
    let parsedDOM: HTMLDocument = htmlParser.parseFromString('<html>' + body + '</html>', 'text/html');

    // ------- code to modify DOM goes here -------

    return parsedDOM.documentElement.innerHTML;
}
```

> **Issue:** If I print parsedDOM or parsedDOM.documentElement in my debug console,
>   it correctly displays the modified HTML content. Surprisingly,
>   innerHTML or outerHTML property throws no error but returns
>   'undefined'.

My obvious guess was that I might have messed up the format of HTML while modifying my code but even if I comment everything inside my function except the three lines above, the behavior is still the same.

What could I possibly be doing wrong here?
Thanks, I am pretty new to React-Native and typescript so I won't be surprised if I am missing some trivial and obvious thing here.

Answer (score 0):

```
htmlParser.parseFromString
```

returns something that looks like the DOM, that has some methods in common with the DOM but not all of them. It does not have `.innerHTML`. Real browser DOM have it.

From what is written here https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-html-parser innerHTML is not available

So why does it not throw an Error ? Because that is how JavaScript Objects work.

```
console.log({}.innerHTML) // No Error
```

How to force an error ?

There are 2 solutions, One is to use strict mode and enable strict mode warnings in the console. The other is wrap things with `Proxy`s that checks for `hasOwnProperty` for example.

Comment: Thanks. Same link states that there exists attribute 'documentElement' which returns an HTMLElement which extends Element and Element has 'innerHTML' property. So I thought this should work.
Is there any solution for me here?

Comment: find another better package, or improve the existing one. Documentations is not always perfect.